# Compare two columns in two csv files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have two csv files with same columns name:

- In file1 I got all the people who made a test and all the status (passed/missed)
- In file2 I only have those who missed the test

I'd like to compare file1.column1 and file2.column1

- If they match then compare file1.column4 and file2.column4
- If they are different remove item line from file2

I can't figure how to do that.
I looked things with pandas but I didn't manage to do anything that works

**What I have is:**

file1.csv:

```
name;DOB;service;test status;test date
Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Missed;01/01/2019
foo;02/11/1989;office;Passed;01/01/2019
bar;03/09/1972;sales;Passed;02/03/2018
Doe;25/03/1958;garage;Missed;02/04/2019
Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Passed;04/05/2019
```

file2.csv:

```
name;DOB;service;test status;test date
Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Missed;01/01/2019
Doe;25/03/1958;garage;Missed;02/04/2019
```

**What I want to get is:**

file1.csv:

```
name;DOB;service;test status;test date
Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Missed;01/01/2019
foo;02/11/1989;office;Passed;01/01/2019
bar;03/09/1972;sales;Passed;02/03/2018
Doe;25/03/1958;garage;Missed;02/04/2019
Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Passed;04/05/2019
```

file2.csv:

```
name;DOB;service;test status;test date
Doe;25/03/1958;garage;Missed;02/04/2019
```

Comment: Which columns do you mean with 'Column1' and 'Column4'. Can you give names?

Comment: And why did row 2 in file2 get removed? They are exactly the same in both dataframes.

Comment: column1=name and column4= status

Comment: row2 in file2 is removed because `Passed` (ssucceeded) the test  file1 keep everyone status at each time and file2 contains only people who missed the test and have to retry

Comment: first smith missed the test

Comment: Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Missed;01/01/2019

Comment: then he passed it

Comment: Smith;12/12/2012;compta;Passed;04/05/2019

Comment: so i remove smith from missed tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you will have to open:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',delimiter=';')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',delimiter=';')
```

Treating the data frame, because of white spaces found

```py
    df1.columns= df1.columns.str.strip()
    df2.columns= df2.columns.str.strip()
    # Assuming only strings
    df1 = df1.apply(lambda column: column.str.strip())
    df2 = df2.apply(lambda column: column.str.strip())
```

**The solution expected, Assuming that your name is UNIQUE.**

Merging the files

```py
    new_merged_df = df2.merge(df1[['name','test status']],'left',on=['name'],suffixes=('','file1'))
```

DataFrame Result:

```py
    name         DOB service test status   test date test statusfile1
0  Smith  12/12/2012  compta      Missed  01/01/2019           Missed
1  Smith  12/12/2012  compta      Missed  01/01/2019           Passed
2    Doe  25/03/1958  garage      Missed  02/04/2019           Missed
```

Filtering based on the requirements and removing the rows with the name with different test status.

```py
    filter = new_merged_df['test status'] != new_merged_df['test statusfile1']
    # Check if there is different values
    if len(new_merged_df[filter]) > 0:
       drop_names = list(new_merged_df[filter]['name'])
       # Removing the values that we don't want
       new_merged_df = new_merged_df[~new_merged_df['name'].isin(drop_names)]
```

Removing columns and storing

```py
    # Saving as a file with the same schema as file2
    new_merged_df.drop(columns=['test statusfile1'],inplace=True)
    new_merged_df.to_csv('file2.csv',delimiter=';',index=False)
```

Result

```
  name         DOB service test status   test date
2  Doe  25/03/1958  garage      Missed  02/04/2019
```